# Авто прокрутка AnimatedList Flutter

Tags: flutter

Не прокручивает до конца при появлении нового элемента в AnimatedList.
Нашел SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback и он не помог видимо из-за того что тут несколько кадров при появлении нового элемента, и поэтому _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent не учитывает и прокручивает только до предпоследней. Как поймать событие что элемент полностью готов или приостановить до появления?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

ScrollController _scrollController;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('AnimatedList')),
        body: BodyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BodyWidgetState createState() {
    return new BodyWidgetState();
  }
}

class BodyWidgetState extends State<BodyWidget> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  }

  // the GlobalKey is needed to animate the list
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();

  // backing data
  List<String> _data = ['Item 0', 'Item 1'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: 400,
          child: AnimatedList(
            controller: _scrollController,
            key: _listKey,
            initialItemCount: _data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
              return _buildItem(_data[index], animation);
            },
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text(
            'Add item',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            _addItem();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(String item, Animation animation) {
    return SizeTransition(
      sizeFactor: animation,
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            item,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _addItem() {
    String item = "Item  ${_data.length}";
    _data.add(item);
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(_data.length - 1); 
    // вот тут я пытаюсь прокрутить 
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Метод `_listKey.currentState.inserItem()` в качестве доп. параметра принимает св-во `duration`, которое отвечает за длительность проигрывания анимации. Стандартное его значение равняется 300мс. Следовательно в вашем методе `_addItem` следует добавить задержку >= 300 мс. Вот как это должно выглядеть для вашего кода:

```dart
  void _addItem() {
    String item = "Item  ${_data.length}";
    _data.add(item);
    _listKey.currentState.insertItem(_data.length - 1); 
    // 300 ms delay
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      _scrollController.animateTo(
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      );
    });
  }
```